# Create a corpus from df including doc names

Tags: r, quanteda

I'm reading all my textfiles into a df with the readtext package.

```
df <- readtext(directory, "*.txt")
```

The .txt files get stored in a df with `doc_id` (name of the document) and text (content).

Before I upgraded to the newest version of quanteda, the `doc_id` was stored in the corpus object when I created my corpus using:

```
corpus <- corpus(df)
```

But now this doesn't work anymore, the 'documents'-df of the corpus object only stores the 'texts'-values, but not the `doc_id`-values anymore.

How do I get back my `doc_id` into my corpus object?

Answer (score 1):

That's because of a [bug](https://github.com/quanteda/quanteda/issues/1316) that we fixed prior to v1.2.0.  When constructing a corpus from a data.frame, some field is required for a document id, and by default this is the **readtext** `doc_id`.

If you want it also as a document variable, you can do it this way.  First, I read in some texts from the system files of the **readtext** package, for a reproducible example.

```
library("readtext")
library("quanteda")

packageVersion("readtext")
## [1] ‘0.50’
packageVersion("quanteda")
## [1] ‘1.2.0’

df <- readtext(paste0(DATA_DIR, "txt/EU_manifestos/*.txt"), encoding = "LATIN1")
df
## readtext object consisting of 17 documents and 0 docvars.
## # data.frame [17 × 2]
## doc_id                  text                
## <chr>                   <chr>               
## 1 EU_euro_2004_de_PSE.txt "\"PES · PSE \"..." 
## 2 EU_euro_2004_de_V.txt   "\"Gemeinsame\"..." 
## 3 EU_euro_2004_en_PSE.txt "\"PES · PSE \"..." 
## 4 EU_euro_2004_en_V.txt   "\"Manifesto\n\"..."
## 5 EU_euro_2004_es_PSE.txt "\"PES · PSE \"..." 
## 6 EU_euro_2004_es_V.txt   "\"Manifesto\n\"..."
```

When we create the corpus from this, we see no document variables.

```
crp <- corpus(df)
crp
## data frame with 0 columns and 17 rows
```

But it's trivial to add them:

```
docvars(crp, "doc_id") <- df$doc_id
head(docvars(crp))
##                                          doc_id
## EU_euro_2004_de_PSE.txt EU_euro_2004_de_PSE.txt
## EU_euro_2004_de_V.txt     EU_euro_2004_de_V.txt
## EU_euro_2004_en_PSE.txt EU_euro_2004_en_PSE.txt
## EU_euro_2004_en_V.txt     EU_euro_2004_en_V.txt
## EU_euro_2004_es_PSE.txt EU_euro_2004_es_PSE.txt
## EU_euro_2004_es_V.txt     EU_euro_2004_es_V.txt
```

Note that you are strongly discouraged from accessing the internals of the corpus object through its data.frame element `df$documents`.  Using the accessor `docvars()` and replacement `docvars()<-` will work in the future, but the internals of the corpus are likely to change.